# How to update "order" field in mongodb multiple documents collection accroding to request array?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I use this code to do this:

```
  const update = async (item) => {
                await Service.updateOne({ _id: item._id }, { order: item.order });
            };
            arr.forEach((item) => update(item));
```

can I do the same using updateMany method and making only one request to DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use bulkWrite

For this example i have mapped a data array and for each entry set updateOne operation with _id filter and instruction to update the value field with item.value value

```
const operations = data.map((item) => ({
   updateOne: {
     filter: { _id: item._id },
     update: { $set: { value: item.value } }
   }
}));

Service.bulkWrite(operations)
```

Here is a link to the documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/

Hope this helps!